# How do Online App Creator work? Is there any example source code to look?

Tags: java, android, iphone

There are a lot of solutions for creating an app online like http://www.theappbuilder.com.

How do they build these apps? Is there any example source code to look at cause these tools are all over the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This app builder uses Webview, set to full screen what shows HTML5  page that you can make with this tool. I think it might be possible to see some code. These kinds of tools are helpful for some easy apps, if you want full control and make something more complicated you will need to use Android-sdk or some other hybrid sdk-s(appcelerator, corona-sdk, adobe flash buider and so on).

Comment: do ya have a link to Webview?

Comment: I mean that they create apk, what has a simple webview, that shows web page. Webview is web browser in android device.

Comment: is there an open source alternative to see how these basic builders work?

Comment: Not that i know of, it looses its point if it tells you its business secret. Everyone would set up sites like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ionic for that, i have similar project that i am working on right now since ionic is built in top of angular and html and produce `/www` folder for you and you can simply use command `ionic cordova build android` to convert to the apk, if you want it to run on server you can call those command using php `exec()` command.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment above, you ask about open source alternatives.  Take a look at something like PhoneGap.  It is close enough that it should give you an understanding of the general approach.